# Can apps installed by tar archive in home directory affect other system directories?

Tags: filesystem

When I install applications like Android Studio or programs like Oracle JDK in home directory by extracting tar archives, after running the `.sh` file, they make changes on home directory such as making configuration files and folders. I want to know that can they access other system folders in my root directory and make changes in them?

Comment: They can make any modifications to anything they please that you can from your personal account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can, but the consensus is that they should not.

Installation from `tar.gz` should be of 2 kinds of installations. an installer or install script that offers using ...

1. `/opt/` as the installation path and then put everything except a symlink in `/etc/` to the binary in `/opt/` so a service gets started on boot. This one requires `sudo` and tends to be for larger projects (think jasperserver, a mysql from source) where more than 1 user use the software or where the software is a server.
2. `/home/$USER/` and a subdirectory in there named after the software where everything gets installed there. This one does not require `sudo` and should not install anything outside of your home.

   When you use this kind of installation and the installer asks for your `sudo` password this is a red flag. You need to stop and investigate. List the installer on screen and check why it is asking for it. Or ask on AskUbuntu ;)

I have yet to see software that did not follow this.

Only installers made for that specific OS (.DEB for Ubuntu/Debian, .RPM for Redhat etc.) should use the specific directories described in the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/).

Comment: So `tar.gz` programs extracted in `/home/$USER/` cannot access  outside of my home without my password?

Comment: Yes. That software can only go to places your  user can go. So outside `/home/$USER/` most places are not allowed. Only if you mess up your permissions installing software can be done without a sudo password (you could install apache and do a chmod 777 /var/www/html and any software can screw your system but we do not do that ;-) )